# Why is the Android context menu empty?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, menu

I have the context menu layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
  <item
        android:id="@+id/share_btn"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_delete_black_24dp"
        android:title=""
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
  <item
        android:id="@+id/edit_btn"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_edit_black_24dp"
        android:title=""
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
  <item
        android:id="@+id/remove_btn"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_delete_black_24dp"
        android:title=""
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

And Fragment, where I am trying to to show the menu:

```
class OverviewFragment: Fragment() {

/* some code */

override fun onCreateContextMenu(menu: ContextMenu, v: View, menuInfo: ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo?) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo)
    this.activity!!.menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.binge_card_menu, menu)
 }
/*some code */ }
```

But the layout didn't show:

[image]

But listeners worked, and if I make the menu programmatically everything shows correctly, so I don't know why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happens because you are using empty string as title:

```
 <item
    android:id="@+id/share_btn"
    android:title=""
    .../>
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
  <item
        android:id="@+id/share_btn"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_delete_black_24dp"
        android:title="Share"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
  <item
        android:id="@+id/edit_btn"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_edit_black_24dp"
        android:title="Edit"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
  <item
        android:id="@+id/remove_btn"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_delete_black_24dp"
        android:title="Remove"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use empty string.

```
<item
android:id="@+id/share_btn"
**android:title="Share"**
.../>
```